# How to upload video to favorite/playlist using gdata in objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, gdata-api

i am trying to upload a video to favorite in my account but it shows **Invalid request Uri** and status code =400

i dont understand how should i format my request

my code

```
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:
                 http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/username/favorite];
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setPostValue:@"gdata.youtube.com" forKey:@"Host"];
[request setPostValue:@"application/atom+xml" forKey:@"Content-Type"];
[request setPostValue:@"CONTENT_LENGTH" forKey:@"Content-Length"];
[request setPostValue:@"" forKey:@"AuthSubToken"];
[request setPostValue:@"2" forKey:@"GData-Version"];
[request setPostValue:developer_key forKey:@"X-GData-Key"];
[request setPostValue:xml_data forKey:@"API_XML_Request"];

[request setDelegate:self];
[request setDidFailSelector:@selector(requestFailed:)];
[request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(gotTheResponse:)];
[[networkQueue go];
```

i have auth token and developer key, VIDEO_ID.but m not sure how to pass xml data in post request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <id>VIDEO_ID</id>
 </entry>
```

NSString *xml_data = contains xml data in string form

Comment: i want to add to you tube account!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSString *developer_key;

GDataEntryYouTubeFavorite *favorite = [GDataEntryYouTubeFavorite entry];

[favorite setIdentifier:video_id];

service = [[GDataServiceGoogleYouTube alloc] init];

[service setUserCredentialsWithUsername:user_name password:user_pass];

[service setYouTubeDeveloperKey:developer_key];

NSURL *feedURL = [GDataServiceGoogleYouTube youTubeURLForUserID:@"default" 
                                 userFeedID:kGDataYouTubeUserFeedIDFavorites];

[service fetchEntryByInsertingEntry:favorite forFeedURL:feedURL 
                           delegate:self 
                didFinishSelector:@selector(subscribeTicket:finishedWithEntry:)];
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot wrong with the request: it lacks a ClientLogin or OAuth authentication token, there's no Content-Length, the XML lacks namespaces, and probably other issues.

Have you considered using the [GData Objective-C client library](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/)?  Using the library, adding a favorite looks like this:

```
  NSURL *favoritesFeedURL = [GDataServiceGoogleYouTube youTubeURLForUserID:username
                                                                userFeedID:kGDataYouTubeUserFeedIDFavorites];
  GDataServiceGoogleYouTube *service = [self youTubeService];
  [service fetchFeedWithURL:favoritesFeedURL
          completionHandler:^(GDataServiceTicket *ticket, GDataFeedBase *feed, NSError *error) {

            if (error == nil) {
              // add the new favorite
              GDataEntryYouTubeVideo *entry = [GDataEntryYouTubeVideo videoEntry];
              [entry setIdentifier:videoID];

              [service fetchEntryByInsertingEntry:entry
                                       forFeedURL:[[feed postLink] URL]
                                completionHandler:^(GDataServiceTicket *ticket, GDataEntryBase *entry, NSError *error) {

                                  if (error == nil) {
                                    // succeeded
                                  } else {
                                    NSLog(@"Error inserting new favorite: %@", error); 
                                  }
                                }];

            } else {
              NSLog(@"Error fetching favorites feed: %@", error); 
            }

          }];
```

Comment: some errors: 1)_Block_object_dispose, 2)_NSConcreteGlobalBlack, 3)_Block_object_assign ,4) _NSConcreteStackBlock

Comment: some warnings: 1) GDataServiceGoogleYouTube may not respond to fetchFeedWithURL 2)GDataServiceGoogleYouTube may not respond to fetchEntryByInsertingEntry 3) GDataServiceGoogleYouTube may not respond to youTubeService

Comment: is there any way to achieve this without using PLBlocks?If not can u suggest me how to avoid the errors & warnings

Comment: i am trying to accomplish this task in iPad 3.2, base sdk = 3.2, DeploymentOS X target:10.5, deployment target = iPhone OS 3.2. I have also imported PLBlocks framework. i also tried the working as shown ob this link:http://code.google.com/p/plblocks/ but no success.There is no listing of GCC4.2(Plausible Blocks)

Comment: hey i have integrated PLBLocks without any errors but coz of warnings mentioned above the app crashes.what to do?????

Comment: m also using the latest gdata library which contains the code for blocks, i have checked it but still coz of warnings the app crashes